# Use some EFI loader to boot MBR

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

For compatibility reasons I had to install Debian via BIOS emulation rather than native EFI. As the EFI internal bootloader takes ages to look for bootable legacy disks I'd like to change the bootloader or chainload the existing GRUB2.

Should I use an additional loader for chainloading? Is it possible to enable a BIOS emulation in some EFI-loaders like refind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rEFInd can chainload grub. Install it to a vFAT partition and let rEFInd auto-detect your MBR.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed answer? Where can one find rEFind ( which wesite etc) and how to install it?

Comment: It's here: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ -- you need the binary built with EDK2 toolchain, not GNU EFI (the latter lacks this ability).

Comment: refind can chain load grub-efi, not the bios grub.

Comment: Yes it works...